# Read an index of a pandas dataframe convert to header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header

Python Beginner question:
I have a dataframe with a X x Y shape. I want to convert it to a 1 x (X*Y) header file. So for example as below a 4x4 pandas df:

```
a   e   i   m
b   f   j   n
c   g   k   o
d   h   l   p
```

I want the output to be 1x16 (a,b,c,d,e,f...o,p). This has to be a COLUMN not row entry.
Is dataframe manipulation the best way or should I use numpy? I am starting from an xls file of X x Y.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as nr
import math

    %matplotlib inline
    #Load Data & Quick Peak
    hdr = pd.read_excel('header.xls', header=None)
    print(hdr)
    hdr.shape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `melt()` like so:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'col2': ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
    'col3': ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
    'col4': ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.melt()['value'])
```

result:

```
0     a
1     b
2     c
3     d
4     e
5     f
6     g
7     h
8     i
9     j
10    k
11    l
12    m
13    n
14    o
15    p
```

Comment: is there a melt for column entries? I wanted 1row by 16columns

Comment: You can add `transpose()` so the final line will look like this: `print(df.melt().transpose())` and the needed values will be in second row which you can extract or delete the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Reshaping the transpose of your dataframe 'hdr' according to choice may help. For example,

```
hdr = pd.read_excel('header.xls', header = None)   
hdr_arr = df.T.values.reshape(1,16)
```

This converts the dataframe to an array of 1x16.